# Laravel custom event not being triggered by eloquent event when model update run as scheduled task

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom event being triggerred by the `updated` Eloquent model event. This custom event is working when an update is done manually, (ie outside a Scheduled Task) but **not** when the update is done via a Scheduled Task

Model code

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model {
    self::updated(function ($location) {
        event(new LocationRefresh($location));
    });
}
```

Here's the event listener:

```
<?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use App\Models\Location;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class LocationRefresh extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $id;
    public $closed;
    public $closed_until;

    public function __construct(Location $location)
    {
        $this->id = $location->id;
        $this->closed = $location->closed;
        $this->closed_until = $location->closed_until;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [
            'private-location-'.$this->id
        ];
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `updated` is only triggered if the update has certainly been performed and succeeded. Are you sure your scheduled job does perform a successful update of the model? Also, how does the event listener you expect to jump in look like?

Comment: Absolutely. I've updated the question with the event that's successfully fired outside of cron.

Comment: The only weird thing I can spot is your `broadcastOn()` method because you do not use the `PrivateChannel` class like described in the docs. Are you working on an older version of Laravel 5?